# How do I fix the error "failed to add i915 component master (-19)"?

Tags: i915

I get the error message

> snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)

at boot up (along with some other error messages at shut down) on a system running Ubuntu 14.04. If I restore a backup where no Nvidia drivers were installed the system boots up and shuts down just fine. Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: snd_hda_intel was sound card driver and i915 was graphic card driver.Why did you install nvidia drivers?When your graphic card was Intel 915.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dual-GPU laptop and have now chosen to use the Nvidia GPU only, this message can happen as the chipset-integrated Intel HDA sound card has provisions for HDMI/DisplayPort audio, but now that the Nvidia GPU is selected for exclusive use, the i915 GPU and its HDMI/DisplayPort circuitry is now disabled.

The firmware *should* have had new configuration for the integratd sound card too for this GPU configuration, to clean up any references to the HDMI/DisplayPort output(s) from this sound card. Instead, the firmware programmer had done it the easy way. The result is that the HD Audio driver detects the missing connection that should be there according to the firmware information, and outputs a notification message about it. As this is a Linux-only issue that has no effect other than one extra message, the system vendor is unlikely to expend any significant effort to get the firmware fixed.

The message is harmless: you don't need to do anything about it. Just remember that you probably have two "sound cards" now: the one built into the chipset will be responsible for any analog inputs & outputs, and any HDMI or DisplayPort outputs that may be mentioned in its configuration will be non-functional, as the Intel GPU is not in use. Instead, the Nvidia GPU will probably be presenting its own HD Audio-compatible sound card that will only have HDMI/DisplayPort digital outputs.

I think some newer Linux kernel versions have changed the text of that message to make it clearer, and also lowered its priority so it might go to system log only instead of appearing on screen at every boot.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue of having Secure boot turned on in the bios settings. There are various ways to fix this, but turning off secure boot in the bios is the easiest one.